# How Do I Make "Super Awesome Vertical Timeline" use a JSON data source?

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-isotope

I've found a really nice looking vertical timeline based upon the jQuery Isotope masonry plugin here:
https://github.com/wnyc/Timeline

This seems to use a Google Spreadsheet as a data source.

Can anybody assist with making this plugin use a JSON datasource instead?

I intend on populating this from a server side script with SQL calls.

Many Thanks,
Andy

Comment: Rather than asking "Can you help me...?" post what you've tried and ask "What am I doing wrong?" You will get less downvotes that way. This is a site to help answer questions, not solicit free development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading through the README page that you linked to, it's obvious that this widget uses Tabletop.js to load data. If you read the Tabletop.js page [README](https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop), you find that all it does is convert a Google spreadsheet into JSON data. This means that Timeline already works with JSON data:

(From the github page)

```
function init() {
  Tabletop.init( { key: '0AmYzu_s7QHsmdDNZUzRlYldnWTZCLXdrMXlYQzVxSFE',
               callback: function(data, tabletop) { console.log(data) },
               simpleSheet: true } )
}
```

> Will give you

```
[ { name: "Carrot", category: "Vegetable", healthiness: "Adequate" }, 
  { name: "Pork Shoulder", category: "Meat", healthiness: "Questionable" }, 
  { name: "Bubblegum", category: "Candy", healthiness: "Super High"} ]
```

> Yes, that easy.

All you have to do is find where Tabletop functions are called (you have access to the source code) and replace that with an AJAX call. Since you haven't posted any code that you have tried, I can't help you any more than that.